# How to resolve 'cuchar' error in VScode when running program

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can't run the program because cuchar got error.

I have just installed VScode and msys but when i run a program, this error showup
[error screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHEPD.png)
'mbrtoc16' has not been declared in '::'
the global scope has no "mbrtoc16"
'c16rtomb' has not been declared in '::'
the global scope has no "c16rtomb"
'mbrtoc32' has not been declared in '::'
the global scope has no "mbrtoc32"
'c32rtomb' has not been declared in '::'
the global scope has no "c32rtomb"

How can i fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The same is happening with me also. For the time being, I just opened the header file 'stdc++.h' and commented the line '#include <cuchar>'. Now it is working fine. In future if got some fix. Then I will update it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Visual Studio Code. I reinstalled it and it works.
Make sure to desinstall VS code app (and MSYS2 if you use C++). Then install VS code app at the official web.